# Safari jQuery 2.1.4 error

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari

I am using jQuery 2.1.4 with my application. When I tried to open on safari 9.0.1 I received following error during jQuery import:

> Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: input[type=checkbox at jquery-2.1.4.min.js:398.

This is using a minified jQuery file from official site. On other browsers it works without errors, only on Safari there is error and my other scripts do now work because of this.

Any advice?

Update:
On expanded error in safari this is information:
[Safari error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s1OdZ.png)

Comment: Add the code that uses `input[type=check`...

Comment: This is error in jquery library and I cannot find where it uses it. I only have that it is on line 398. If I expand the error there are some additional info which I will update in post.

Comment: Does full jQuery version log same syntax error ? Can include `html` , `js` used that logs syntax error at Question ? , create stacksnippets https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/ to demonstrate ? See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: The error message refers to `main.js` line 4. You need to include sufficient code to reproduce the problem. It doesn't appear to be simply loading jQuery that triggers it.

Comment: Thank you, I got lost because of first message :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From error message appear closing `]` is missing at selector expression ?

Try `$("input[type=checkbox]")`, where closing `]` is included within attribute selector expression.

```js
$(function() {
  $("input[type=checkbox]").change(function() {
    alert(this.checked)
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<input type="checkbox" />
```

Comment: Thank you for help. I did not see that the main error was in my javascript file,until Quentin did not mention it.